# How to make await work with redux Saga in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

The `await` does not seem to work with Redux saga. I need to wait for my API call to finish and then execute the remaining code. What happens now is that `AFTER CALL` gets printed before the `RESPONSE` which means await does not seem to work at all. I'm using async calls but not sure what needs to be done extra from the redux saga side?

```
async componentWillMount() {
    console.log("BEFORE CALL")
    await this.props.getUserCredit()
    console.log("AFTER CALL")

}

mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    getUserCredit: () => dispatch(getUserCredit()),
  }
};

connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```

`Action`

```
export const getUserCredit = () => {
  return {
    type: GET_USER_CREDIT,
  };
};
```

`Redux Saga`

```
const getUserCreditRequest = async () => {
  const response = await Api.get(getCreditUrl)
  console.log("REPONSE!!!")
  console.log(response)
  return response
}

function* getUserCredits() {
  try {
    const response = yield call(getUserCreditRequest);
    if (response.status === okStatus) {
      yield put({
        userCredit: response.data.userCredit
      }
      ));
    }
  } catch (error) {}
}

export function* getUserCredit() {
  yield takeLatest(GET_USER_CREDIT, getUserCredits);
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([fork(getUserCredit)]);
}
```

Comment: i don't see any action being `dispatch`ed?

Comment: If you see component will Mount method that will call the action and then thus caught by saga middleware for the respective type and then it gets triggered.

Comment: I clearly see that. You need to use `mapDispatchToProps` to dispatch `GET_USER_CREDIT` action; NOT by just simply calling it.

Comment: P.S [don't use `componentWillMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount)

Comment: It would be great if you post your answer by refactoring the code or how you want it to be implemented then it would clarify things for me as well. What alternative do you suggest if not componentWillMount? One other thing that could be done is to call the action when leaving the previous component?

Answer (score 2):

Normally, init / fetching takes place during `componentDidMount` and don't use `async` or `await` inside components. Let the saga middleware do its thing via `yield`.

```
// In your component
componentDidMount() { // not async
  this.props.getUserCredit(); // dispatch `GET_USER_CREDIT` action 
}

mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    getUserCredit: () => dispatch(getUserCredit()),
  }
};

connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(YourComponent);
```

Comment: In this approach, can you come up with this sequence BEFORE CALL, RESPONSE FROM API and lastly AFTER CALL in the componentDidMount method? This is something I am more interested in ?

Comment: take note that RESPONSE FROM API is more suited after the actual update has been made in reducer so that the component can be updated via `componentDidUpdate` or `mapStateToProps`

Comment: I agree with that, but my question is I need to set my user CREDIT before rendering gets done. So, in that case, this sequence is critical for me. I need to achieve this sequence BEFORE CALL, RESPONSE FROM API and lastly AFTER CALL

Comment: Do you happen to know what am I missing in order to achieve this sequence?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using `async`/`await` pattern. As `redux-saga` handles it by the `yield` keyword. By the time `call` is resolved you will have the value available in `response`.

in `actions.js`, you should have an action that will carry your data to your reducer:

```
export function getUserCredits(userCredit) {
  return {
    type: types.GET_USER_CREDIT_SUCCESS,
    payload: userCredit
  };
}
```

Your saga should handle the API call like so:

```
function* getUserCredits() {
  try {
    const response = yield axios.get(getCreditUrl); <--- This should work
    // No need for if here, the saga will catch an error if the previous call failed
    yield put(actions.getUserCredits(response.data.userCredit));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**: [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/z6y22y357p) of using axios with redux-saga

Comment: It throws me this error `uncaught at check call: argument [object Promise] is not a function` if I do as per your code. Can you correct the code ?

Comment: In addition, `Api` is an axios instance which cannot be called directly in `yield` that is why we need a separate a function to make an API call.

Comment: Even after correcting the syntax, `AFTER` gets printed first it still does not wait for the api call to be finished and then print `AFTER` on the browser.

Comment: Can you try calling the API without making it an axios instance?

Comment: well i would need an instance since I have my base url and other timeout settings in the instance. It does not make sense to call the axios without an instance since I need those settings every time I make a call to the API :(

Comment: I have attached an example to my answer of how to use axios with redux-saga, take a look.

Comment: I tested the code but at this point I am not looking for middleware solutions since it will require alot of changes on my side in the entire project. I am just wondering about the sequence that if await is there then it should wait and then continue with the print statement as suggested in my code.